# Include(insert) new row at SQL with three tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I am stuck with a question:

I want to Include Joy Davies in the TV ad Project (P300) with cost of 800.

I need to change this in `PALLOCATION` table.

Table Name: `EMPLOYEE`

```
Emp_id | Emp_name          | Address            | Area of Expertise
==========================================================================
123456 | Kayleigh Donald   | 23 LakeAvenue      | Script writing
123457 | Fiaz Hussain      | 12 Riverside Drive | Production
123458 | Debbie Jackson    | 17 Long Road       | Design
123459 | Melissa Jefferies | 45 The High Street | Design
123460 | Nirmal Singh      | 34 East Street     | Script writing
123461 | Joy Davies        | 76 Broadway        | Storyboarding
123462 | Daniel Ortez      | 23 The Green       | Production
```

Table Name: `PALLOCATION`

```
Emp_id | PROJECT_ID | STAFF_COST
==============================================
123456 |    P300    | 900
123457 |    P300    | 1500
123456 |    D400    | 2000
123458 |    D400    | 400
123458 |    P200    | 350
123460 |    P200    | 800
123462 |    P200    | 400
```

Table Name: `PROJECTS`

```
PROJECT_ID | Project_name | Client
==============================================
  P300     | TV Ad        | GSK
  D400     | Billboard Ad | GSK 
  P200     | Radio Ad     | Prontaprint
```

I am trying to achieve this by using this sql.

```
INSERT INTO Pallocation (Emp_id, Project_id, Staff_cost)
VALUES ('123461', 'P300', '800')
FROM Pallocation JOIN Employee ON Emp_id E = Emp_id Pa 
    JOIN Project ON Project_id Pr = Project id Pa
    WHERE Emp_name...
```

I realized this seems wrong. Could you please kindly guide me through?

Thank you

Comment: Why are you mixing literal values and a query? That seems a little odd and I can't figure out what you're doing.

Comment: I think the homework questions is essentially about how to apply three separate inserts to all three tables to add a new fact to the database. Try writing three `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Can you please provide more details like, are the values already inserted into Project and Employee tables and now you just need to insert the PAllocation record?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `FROM`

Standard Insert syntax is

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

So you just need:

```
INSERT INTO Pallocation (Emp_id, Project_id, Staff_cost) 
VALUES ('123461', 'P300', '800');
```

Answer (score 0):

just check for nulls to make sure data integrity

```
DECLARE @empID NVARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @projectID NVARCHAR(50)

SELECT @empid = Emp_id from EMPLOYEE WHERE Emp_id = '123461'
SELECT @ProjectID = PROJECT_ID from PROJECTS where PROJECT_ID  = 'P300'

IF (@empid is not null and @ProjectID is not null)
BEGIN
   INSERT INTO PALLOCATION (Emp_id, Project_id, Staff_cost) 
   VALUES (@empid,@ProjectID,'800')
END
```